# "to" in "a source of grievance to the people"

Tags: meaning, prepositions

[cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grievance):
**(1)** *The small amount of compensation is a source of grievance **to** the people forced to leave their homes*.

my variants:
**(2)** *The small amount of compensation is a source of grievance **against** the people forced to leave their homes*.
**(3)** *The small amount of compensation is a source of grievance **of** the people forced to leave their homes*.

Does (1) mean (3)?
Can (1) mean (2)?

To me, "*to*" in (1) is a mistake because as far as I understand:
— nowhere in dictionaries does "*to*" have the meaning "*of*";
— "*grievance **to** the people*" must mean only "*grievance **against** the people*".

So could you please show me in some dictionary that meaning of "*to*" which is used in (1)?

Answer (score 2):

The smallness of the compensation caused the people **to** feel aggrieved. Compare: *bring happiness to someone, be a cause of sorrow to someone* etc.

(2) means the opposite; that someone was angry with the people who were forced to leave their homes (which doesn't make sense). The people had a grievance against the government for not paying more compensation!

Yes, the grievance was 'of' the people, but (1) is much more idiomatic than (3).

Comment: "A **source** of [x]" is also important here. If we were talking about something physical-- "The well is a source of water **to** or **for** the people," not against.